# Wrong Implementation in reusing Loading CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a Loading CSS and found a reusable loading css.

I found this in https://loading.io/css/

I used it in the w3school editor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}
@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="lds-ring">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was able to declare the Class in div but I don't know what mistake I made.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text or code. Include all textual data as text in your question. Additionally, you need to include a clear statement of your problem, and all the necessary code to reproduce it. "I can't find my mistake" isn't a problem we can help you with, as you've given us no indications of what you're trying to do and where you're failing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to avoid the w3school editor and rather use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [Codepen](https://codepen.io/).

Your example isn't working because it's missing part of the html code. If you look at the css declarations:

```
.lds-ring div
.lds-ring div:nth-child(1)
.lds-ring div:nth-child(2)
.lds-ring div:nth-child(3)
```

You see that it's trying to style 3 child `divs` inside `lds-ring`.

You just need to edit your html structure:

```
<div class="lds-ring">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Working example:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}
@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-ring">
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
</div>
```